# Win Server 2003 VPS - MailEnable?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, smtp, vps

I've got a 64bit Windows 2003 VPS server.

I need SMTP and POP for a low traffic website.  Essentially there will be 1 POP user (admin@mywebsite.com).  I want to do everything possible to make sure that the SMTP gets there, and isn't blocked as spam.

Is http://www.mailenable.com/ ok, or would you recommend something else?

I'll be testing against: http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of hosting outfits are using MailEnable. It's also packaged with Plesk, which is what a lot of the hosters are using. The free version is very capable, minus IMAP and encrypted protocol support.